# C++: insert a negative character value into a string literal?

Tags: c++, string, ascii

I have a text renderer that uses negative char values from strings to render custom symbols in a font I made, instead of regular ascii text.

```
text.write("Hello! _"); // insert a heart at the underscore somehow...
                        // the heart's value is char -10
```

Is there anyway to get a negative char value, written statically inside the double quotes?  Or is there a way to do this outside of the quotes, but still as a string literal?

*Edit:*

To clarify a little, I have to use a `char` array in this particular case unfortunately.  The code internally uses `std::string`, and all the positive values are taken by standard ascii glyphs.  My goal is to be able to inject a negative number to represent extra symbols, into a string literal.  So the following would be true:

```
const char * literal = "a literal w/ a negative char value as the 10th element"
literal[9] == -10; // would be true
```

Comment: Alt 3 gives you the heart: ♥, maybe you can store it as a string and replace all '_' chars with that string. It depends, however, on the encoding of your code file whether this is possible.

Comment: @invalid_id - The extra symbols, like hearts and stuff, don't correspond to any standard in this case unfortunately since I made the font, but that is good to know! ♥

Comment: Not sure if I understand but you could use escape sequences: `"Hello \u2665"`

Comment: I think it is `\xf5` (`f5` is hexadecimal `256 - 10`).

Comment: @Marco - Is there anyway to make it a negative number?  I'll try out what zch suggested actually, lemme see

Comment: Don't think so, but if you use unsigned values you will always end up using positive integers. I'm really not sure what you're trying to accomplish here

Comment: zch - What you suggested worked out actually!  I am wondering though if I can count on that overflow behaviour.  If it only matters on the compiling machine, that'll be good enough for me I think

Comment: `'\xf5'` is a `char`, if you are on a system with plain char being signed (and 8-bit) then this is implementation-defined but most likely to actually be a negative char

Comment: signed or unsiged is just the way you treat the value of that bit pattern

Comment: I got confused by my own suggestion. I think it should be `f6` instead. Is `f5` really working for you or is it showing neighboring character?

Comment: zch - My font has a lot of hearts in it actually, aha. It may be a neighboring glyph, but that's okay.  I can simply make named constants of string literals containing only the code, then use compile time literal concatenation to splice them in

Answer (score 4):

You can write `"Hello! \xf6"`. f6<sub>16</sub> = -10 + 256

This works, because in 8-bit 2-complement integers negative values `-128 .. -1` have the same bit representations as 256 bigger unsigned values `128 .. 255`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you did not get the point how positive and negative integers are represented in memory.

Each "unsigned char" > 127 will be interpreted as a "signed char" < 0, i.e. when you use characters which are not in the ASCII-Set and interpret them as a signed char, they are automatically negative.

So I see two general approaches for you to enter "negative" character values:

- Either you enter characters from another charset which extend the ASCII-Charset and are fixed to one byte per character, e.g. "ISO-8859-1". Not a good choice in my opinion as you run intro troubles when the file encoding is not set properly, but that should do the trick.
- Or you use the escape sequences to define the byte directly, e.g. you enter some "unsigned char" >= \x80.

Some references for you:

- http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/5/5c/Zahlenkreis_sint3.jpg
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29
- http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html